# Regex to match any character repeated three or more times in R

Tags: regex, r

What is the Regex to match any character repeated three or more times in R (e.g. "aaargh", "arrrrrgh", "yesssssss")? I read the solution for [Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37162058/regular-expression-to-match-any-character-repeated-exactly-twice), [PHP and PCRE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14375402/regexp-how-to-match-a-string-that-doesnt-have-any-character-repeated-3-times) on Stack Overflow, but they don't seem to be applicable to R. Thanks.

Comment: I believe that would be `([[:alpha:]])\1\1`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use `grep`

```
 grep("(.)\\1{2,}", v1)
```

#### data

```
 v1 <- c("aaargh", "arrrrrgh", "yesssssss")
```