# How to match identical characters in regex in R

Tags: r, regex

I can't seem to figure out how to match **identical** characters in regex in R.
Suppose I have this data:

```
dt <- c("12345", "asdf", "#*§", "AAAA", ";;;;", "9999", "%:=+")
```

I'm able to extract all strings that consist exactly of **any** 4 non-whitespace characters, for example like this:

```
pattern <- "\\S{4}"
extract <- function(x) unlist(regmatches(x, gregexpr(pattern, x, perl = T)))
extract(dt)
[1] "1234" "asdf" "AAAA" ";;;;" "9999" "%:=+"
```

But what I really want to match are those strings in which the **same** character is repeated 4 times, giving this ouput:

```
[1] "AAAA" ";;;;" "9999"
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Change the quantifier in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38263441/5325862) to `{3}`

Comment: Try a capture group and reference it... It gets a little tricky because you need to capture it then use a back-reference to look for 3 more like this: `(\\S)\\1{3}` so you have 4 characters total.

Comment: @dvo Thanks a lot: `grep("(\\S)\\1{3}", dt, value = T)`outputs `[1] "AAAA" ";;;;" "9999"`, i.e., the desired result